# Connect Manager not showing some extensions

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect

After installing a few extensions, they for some reason don't show up in the Connect Manager. Modules like: M2E, Jemoon_Htmlminify, Lest_FPC, PulseStorm_Launcher, etc.

They are all installed, but they are not listed there. And when I try and upgrade them (by installing them again via Connect Manager), I get this error:

> CONNECT ERROR: Package 'm2epro_ebay_magento' is invalid
>   './app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Block/Adminhtml/Account/Grid.php'
>   already exists

It then halts my magento installation, until I delete the file maintenance.flag in my magento folder.

I've tried running:

1. ./mage sync but it's not working.

What's going on here? I'm running Magento 1.9

Comment: Did you install all these extensions via the Magento Connect Manager?

Comment: Yes, all the extensions were installed via Connect Manager

Comment: Normally, each installed extension has an XML file under `var/package/`. Maybe the files of these extensions are missing there because of e.g. a permission issue? Additionally, consider not using the Connect Manager - it creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: Seemingly you are right! The troubled extensions are set at permission level 666, while the others are 777. I tried to change said extensions to 777 but it still didn't help!?? Any ideas?

Comment: As long as the XML files are present under `var/package/`, the Connect manager should show them anyway...

Comment: Well, they are in var/package/ 
I believe this problem began when I upgraded from 1.8.1 to 1.9 (but I can't be 100% sure about that)

Comment: Try [that](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33752/is-there-a-way-to-rebuild-downloader-cache-cfg/33753#33753) and check if that helps.

Comment: Tried above. A ./mage sync --force returned the modules in question with:

Successfully added: community/Pulsestorm_Launcher-1.0.4
etc. 

But they're still not showing in connect manager

Comment: How can I manually uninstall modules? Maybe I'll remove them all, and then try and install them via the command line.

Comment: You can try with `./mage uninstall [codePool] [extensionName]`. If that does not work, you have to remove all files manually. You should use something like [modman](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/) and a VCS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cache.cfg` and `connect.cfg` had *nobody:nobody* as the *username:group* in the downloader/ folder.

Logging into root account, and running `chown username:group <file>` on those two files to the proper *username:group* solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also. Running a chown. Did not work for me.

What I had to do was, rename Cache.cfg and connect.cfg. Looks they had corrupted.Once I renamed next time I accessed Connect. Voila, new versions of the files were created. And I could see all my extensions again.

Answer (score 0):

Download the extension again and **from the root copy package.xml** into `/var/package` open the `package.xml` file.

Get the name then rename file file to match I,e in my case I had to rename `package.xml` to `M2epro_ebay_magento-6.4.10.xml`.

Then I logged out of Magento connect manager and logged back in. Now my extension shows.